# Create select based on routing, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, navigation

I am trying to implement navigation like in [Tree Based Navigation](http://railscasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation) but based on URLs defined in routes.rb (named routes, resources, ...).

Is it possible to retreive a collection of all routes defined in routes.rb?

So I can use it in a select like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :url, Route.all, :url, :name %>
```

Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to the hint of [David Lyod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283234/david-lyod) I solved it!

Here is my code:

helper-method

```
# Methods added to this helper will be available to all templates in the application.
module ApplicationHelper

  def routes_url
    routes = ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes.collect do |route|
      segs = route.segments.inject("") { |str,s| str << s.to_s }
      segs.chop! if segs.length > 1
      segs.chomp("(.:format)")
    end
    routes.delete_if {|x| x.index(':id')}
    return routes.compact.uniq.sort
  end
end
```

and in my view I put:

```
<%= select("page", "url", options_for_select(routes_url), {:include_blank => true})  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes
```

Will list available routes for the application. Will require some parsing to pull out applicable details.